# Best practice of loading a npm module that is not main

Tags: jquery, node.js, module, npm, loading

When I pull in jQuery with `npm install jquery` I can load them with e.g. Webpack like `var jQuery = require('jquery')`.

This will check for the module in node_modules and in the case of jQuery there is a package.json included with `"main": "dist/jquery.js"`.

So far everything is clear, there is no need to give a specific path like `require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js')`.

But let's say I need to load the minified or slim version of jQuery, which is included in the same `/dist` directory.

My ideas of doing this are:

1. edit the `package.json` file's main entry, which isn't very good because that will get overwritten if I pull in a new version with npm
2. give Webpack the complete path to the file like `require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')`

Bot ways don't feel quite clean. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, then you can do `require('jquery/some/other/file')`. In your particular case, I'm not sure you why you'd want to load the minified version; if this is a front end project, presumably you minify the final bundle(s) anyway.

Comment: The minified version ist only an example, there are plenty of usefull use cases like the slim version.

Comment: Fair enough. To me it seems that if a module wanted to expose something to you, it would. I appreciate that you feel there are valid use cases, though, in which case the method shown in my answer is how I've seen it done and seems the "nicest". You are right that you don't want to modify the package.json. You could, however, fork the package, modify the package.json to point to the slim version and install that instead. Someone may even have done that already - worth searching npm.